# Brace expansion into a single argument

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

I am calling a bash function like so:

```
func "foo-A-bar foo-B-bar foo-C-bar"
```

I would like to replace the above with a brace expansion that evaluates to the same single argument. The following doesn't work:

```
func foo-{A,B,C}-bar
```

because that's three separate arguments, not one argument with space-separated values. That is, it is equvalent to:

```
func foo-A-bar foo-B-bar foo-C-bar
```

which is not the same thing as the original call.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the brace expansion result into a positional argument list and expand the arguments as a single expanded string.

```
set -- foo-{A,B,C}-bar
func "$*"
```

The `set` command with the result of the brace expansion, sets the arguments from `$1` as `foo-A-bar` and `$2` as `foo-B-bar` respectively. With these positional arguments in-place, the array expansion `$*` causes them arguments to be combined as a single string joined by the default `IFS` value ( a single white-space )

Answer (score 2):

Create an array first.

```
args=(foo-{A,B,C}-bar)
func "${args[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use command substitution:

```
func "$(echo foo-{A,B,C}-bar)"
```

which is equivalent of using:

```
func "foo-A-bar foo-B-bar foo-C-bar"
```